# Template Matching On Images C#

Tags: c#, template-matching

Let's say I have an image and I want to scan it on my screen (taking screenshot and check there).
Does anyone know what subjects should I research and where? 
I'd really appreciate any help with my algorithm.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, the **EmguCV** library has given me the best results. Here's some sample code of how I made it work:

```
        Image<Bgr, byte> Image1 = new Image<Bgr, byte>(Properties.Resources.Image1); //Your first image
        Image<Bgr, byte> Image2 = new Image<Bgr, byte>(Properties.Resources.Image2); //Your second image

        double Threshold = 0.8; //set it to a decimal value between 0 and 1.00, 1.00 meaning that the images must be identical

        Image<Gray, float> Matches = Image1.MatchTemplate(Image2, TemplateMatchingType.CcoeffNormed);

        for (int y = 0; y < Matches.Data.GetLength(0); y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < Matches.Data.GetLength(1); x++)
            {
                 if (Matches.Data[y, x, 0] >= Threshold) //Check if its a valid match
                 {
                     //Image2 found within Image1
                 }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot friend, really appreciate it!
Do you know how to save a screenshot with C#?
Or if there is a way to use the current screen as a picture without screenshot?

Comment: I haven't tried that before, but then again google is your friend: https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+Screen+Capture